# Why is the plt.grid function setting a complete grey background for my plotted data instead of just setting some grid lines? Python related

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I started learning data science, and I was taught that I could use `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot my data. Here's a little preview of those (OHLC prices from 1 hour timeframe):

[image: A little preview of my SOLUSDT dataframe]

And also here's the output of `SOLUSDT_close.head().to_dict()` for debugging purposes:

```
{'Close Price': {'2021-06-29 00:59:59.999': 33.65642566,
  '2021-06-29 01:59:59.999': 33.309,
  '2021-06-29 02:59:59.999': 32.76168975,
  '2021-06-29 03:59:59.999': 33.118,
  '2021-06-29 04:59:59.999': 33.267}}
```

So, I'm only interested in plotting the `Close Price` against the `End Date`, and I wrote the following code to do so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the csv file without index
SOLUSDT = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/SolUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe/zip/SOLUSDT-1h-June-29-2021-February-13-2022.csv', index_col=0)

# Create a new df that only contains the date and close price from the previous imported df
SOLUSDT_close = SOLUSDT[['End Date','Close Price']]

# Set the 'Date' column as the actual index
SOLUSDT_close.set_index('End Date', inplace=True) 

# set the breadth and length of the plot as a good mix of values
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))

# set a grid background to the plot
plt.grid(True) 

# set the color of the trend as blue
plt.plot(SOLUSDT_close, 'b')

# give a title to the plot
plt.title('SOLUSDT close price from June 29 2021 to February 13 2022')

# give a label to the x axis
plt.xlabel('Date')

# gove a label to the y axis
plt.ylabel('Close Price')

# plot it
plt.plot(SOLUSDT_close)
```

However, I ended up with an output which was just disappointing:

[image: disappointing output]

As can be seen, the grid lines merged with a grey background, and also it didn't show some of the End Date values that one would expect at the x axis.

If I decide to delete the `plt.grid(True)` statement and run the code again, it ends up plotting the following chart:

[image: not cool chart]

What I would like to achieve, is to plot a chart like this one from [CoinGecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/solana) (obviously ignoring the volumes, but showing the gridlines and some major dates):

[image: desired chart]

May I get some assistance here please?

Comment: Are you using the latest matplotlib and pandas versions?  For some reason, your datetime column is interpreted as string, making a complete mess of the x-axis. The grid lines are drawn at each x tick, and there are just too many of them.  Did you check `print(SOLUSDT_close.info())` to see that all data is in the correct format?

Comment: Hi @JohanC, after typing `print(SOLUSDT_close.info())` on the Spyder console I got the following output:       

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5520 entries, 2021-06-29 00:59:59.999 to 2022-02-13 23:59:59.999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   Close Price  5520 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 86.2+ KB
None` What can i infer from this?

Comment: First, you are supposed to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72282269/edit) this info to your post, not to the comments.  The output clearly shows that your index isn't of datatime type.  Did you check `plt.matplotlib.__version__` and `pd.__version__`?

Comment: My `matplotlib.__version__` is **3.5.2** and my `pd.__version__` is **1.3.5**

Comment: In that case, the problem is in the data. It needs to be in date-time format (usually pandas `read_csv` does that automatically, so something else must be going wrong).

Comment: I typed `print(type(SOLUSDT_close.index[0]))` to know the type of object of the first date and I got `<class 'str'>`, it seems that you are right, do you recommend any pandas function to convert the index column to date format ?

Comment: I tried `print(datetime.strptime(SOLUSDT_close.index[0], '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` and got `ValueError: time data '2021-06-29 00:59:59.999' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` :(

Comment: I would suggest adding `SOLUSDT_close.head().to_dict()` as text to your post, to avoid unnecessary guessing. And/or the code that created/downloaded the data in case it is easily accessible.  Does `pd.to_datetime(SOLUSDT_close.index[0])` give an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue here is that you have too many dates and each of them is plotting its line on the x-axis. One way is to use the keyword `axis` in the [grid](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html) function:

```py
plt.grid(True, axis='y')
```

[image: img1]

The other would be to only select certain times (dates) which you want to put on the x-axis - as you can see now, there are too many of them. Also, the second line for plotting is not necessary. This would be a very quick and dirty example of that but you get the idea:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.read_csv('./sol-usd-max.csv', usecols=['snapped_at','price'])

df.set_index('snapped_at', inplace=True) 

# set the breadth and length of the plot as a good mix of values
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))

# set a grid background to the plot
plt.grid(True, axis='y')
plt.grid(True, axis='x', which='major')

# set the color of the trend as blue
plt.plot(df[::10], 'b')

# give a title to the plot
plt.title('SOLUSDT close price from June 29 2021 to February 13 2022')

# give a label to the x-axis
plt.xlabel('Date')

# give a label to the y axis
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
```

[image]

---

Update

As for the wrong datetime format, converting it to datetime (either by loading it as a datetime or converting it using `df["snapped_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["snapped_at"])`) also fixes the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.read_csv('./sol-usd-max.csv', usecols=['snapped_at','price'], parse_dates=["snapped_at"])

# df.set_index('snapped_at', inplace=True) 

# set the breadth and length of the plot as a good mix of values
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))

# set a grid background to the plot
plt.grid(True)

# set the color of the trend as blue
plt.plot(df["snapped_at"], df["price"], c='b')

# give a title to the plot
plt.title('SOLUSDT close price from June 29 2021 to February 13 2022')

# give a label to the x axis
plt.xlabel('Date')

# give a label to the y axis
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
```

but that was not the main concern of the question. I mean, it would not have happened if the dtypes were correct but it's not directly causing the background to be grey.

[image]

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much sir! You definitely solved my problem. Although after I typed `plt.grid(True, axis='x', which='major')` and ran the code, I still ended up getting the same initial output. Any suggestions for that last point (`major`)?

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I just realized that after using `plt.plot(df[::10], 'b')` the precision of the trend gets lowered, I just wondered if there would be another way of just showing 10 dates at the x axis without affecting the trend, hehe...

Comment: This really are bad solutions, as the problem is in the interpretation of the x values, not in the grid.

Comment: I just noticed that you updated your answer making it the ultimate solution I was looking for!, once again, thank you so much sir @my-work